# Extract file name from find command

Tags: find, basename

I am trying to extract the file name and attaching to mail. But when I send mail the attachment is coming with path name and file name.

Ex: `dir=/home/as123/bill` and `filename=abc.pdf.Z` and I am getting attachment like

```
homeas123billabc.pdf.Z

find $dir -ctime -1 -type f -name "abc*pdf*" -exec basename {} \; -exec uuencode {} {} \; | mailx -s "north" abc@gmail.com
```

`printf` not installed on my machine, without that how to write my script to get only file name as attachment?

Comment: it's a bit unclear what you mean. You are trying to find a file with a specific pattern and send that filename (only the filename, that's why you used `basename`) via mail to abc@gmail.com?

What is your error?

Comment: Forget the `find` part for now. Do you even have the mailing part working correctly? First come up with a `mail_file.sh` script or one liner that does what you want, and then use it in `find`. `find` itself is not a scripting language. You can't just chain `-exec` like that.

Comment: `printf` is not installed? It's a BASH builtin, so you must be using some other shell, right?

Comment: if i remove -exec basename {} \; from my script, mailing is working properly. and attachment is coming like homeas123billabc.pdf.Z (pathname and file name) but i want only file name as attachment. I am using ksh

Comment: @psimon, I suspect he means the `-printf` `find` predicate (as in GNU find) is not available (which can be used to print the basename with `-printf '%f\n'`)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, yes, you may be right.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - you are correct.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you mean that you want the filename as included in the `uuencode` output:

```
begin 644 path/to/the/file.pdf.Z
%=&5S=`H`
`
end
```

not to include the `path/to/the`.

For that, you want the second argument passed to `uuencode` to be the basename. For that you'd need to do it like:

```
find "$dir" -ctime -1 -type f -name "abc*pdf*" -exec sh -c '
  for file do
    uuencode "$file" "$(basename "$file")"
  done' sh {} +
```

Or if your `find` supports `-execdir`:

```
find "$dir" -ctime -1 -type f -name "abc*pdf*" -execdir uuencode {} {} \;
```

Had your `find` supported `-printf`, you could have done it with:

```
find "$dir" -ctime -1 -type f -name "abc*pdf*" -printf '%p\0%f\0' |
  xargs -r0n2 uuencode
```

Comment: thank you Stéphane Chazelas. If find output results in 2 files, will it attach those two files?

Comment: @user2910201, it will output several `begin...end` blocks yes. If you want to send one mail per file, you'll want to insert the `| mailx` inside the `for` loop.